# Bind repository to base class only via Ninject?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I have a base class that has a repository injected into the constructor, now any class that I derive off of it now also needs those parameters, but the repository is only used by the base class, is there a way to bind Ninject to just the base class and not go through the constructor? And most importantly, is it a good idea?

```
public class HtmlPageModel
{

        private readonly IHtmlPageRepository _repository;

        public HtmlPageModel (IHtmlPageRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;

        }
}


public class VideoPageViewModel : HtmlPageModel 
{

        public VideoPageViewModel(IHtmlPageRepository repository) : base(repository)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: You have to rethink your class hierarchy, this is not something you should work around with Ninject

Answer (score 4, accepted):

View models shouldn't have dependencies at all. Inject the repository into the controller and assign the values from there.

Also if many pages are using the same base view model this indicates that some part of the page is shown in many situations or even all the time. In this case it is better to have a custom controller and view for this area and use `Html.RenderAction` to render this part.

Comment: Interesting I haven't looked into areas. I'm trying to keep my controllers thin, so I don't want to be performing anything on the repository in the controller it self. I'm trying to assemble all needed pieces in one view model, which consists of other models...

Comment: Seems that I havn't been clear enough. By area I didn't mean MVC area but an area of the HTML page on the screen. E.g. the status line here on SO where you see your username, reputation, .... This can be done with an own Controller, View, and ViewModel without the need to inherit the ViewModel or the controller. Also keeping the controller slim is a good thing. But delegating work to the view model is bad practice. View Models should be dumb data objects without any logic. You shoud introduce some services that perform some of the tasks and have the controller use them to fill the view models.

Answer (score 2):

I still stand to my previous comment: You have to rethink your class hierarchy, this is not something you should work around with Ninject.

If your base class accepts a repository, so should all of your derived classes. As an alternative you could however inject a specially `NullRepository` into your `VideoPageViewModel` which basically does nothing (see [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern))

Binding by target type can be achieved using `WhenInjectedInto()` in Ninject:

```
kernel.Bind<IHtmlPageRepository>()
      .To<HtmlPageRepository>()
      .WhenInjectedInto<HtmlPageModel>();

kernel.Bind<IHtmlPageRepository>()
      .To<NullRepository>()
      .WhenInjectedInto<VideoPageViewModel>();
```

Comment: and would this be considered a horrible practice?

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same answer as brokenGlass.  Why not just create another base class, and move the attributes/functionality from the your current base class into that one, but don't move the constructor/functionality that relates to the repository.

Comment: not sure I follow. All the attributes and functionality in that base class need the repository to query for stuff that I need in the view model...